# Can't pass CSRF token into form when using Python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, request, python-requests

I'm trying to create a python (3.7) code, that will create a new room at https://bingosync.com/.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests

with open('bingosync.txt', 'r') as myfile:
  jsonstring = myfile.read()

url = "https://bingosync.com/"

csrfToken = requests.Session().get(url).cookies['csrftoken']

params = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfToken, 'room_name' : 'test', 'passphrase' : 'test123', 'nickname' : 'testcode', 'game_type' : '18', 'custom_json' : jsonstring  }
headers = {'x-csrftoken': csrfToken}

r = requests.Session().post(url, data = params, headers = headers)

print(r.content)
```

My problem is that, I'm getting 403 from the request, because of invalid/missing CSRF token

As far as I understand, I need to put the token into the headers, but it doesn't matter if I input

```
'x-csrftoken': csrfToken
```

or

```
'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrfToken
```

It wouldn't return me anything else than 403.

Comment: Try to create single Session as `s = requests.session()` and send both requests as `csrfToken = s.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']` and `r = s.post(url, data = params, headers = headers)`

Comment: Thank you! It seems that it works. The problem is now that, I think, the code doesn't input anything in form, as it returns a webpage with error in the first field (room_name).

Comment: Try to pass cookies from first request  (`c = s.get(url).cookies`) to next request `r = s.post(url, data = params, cookies=c)`

Comment: Thank you for response! The latest problem was actually with how I pass the params into the params in request.